# autoit script option for right click

Tags: windows, batch-file, autoit, right-click

I've wrote a little autoit script,

```
#include <FileConstants.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

Example()
Func Example()
    Local Const $sMessage = "Locate and click on a batch file."
    Local $sFileOpenDialog = FileOpenDialog($sMessage, @DesktopDir & "\", "Batch         files(*.bat; *.exe)", $FD_FILEMUSTEXIST + $FD_MULTISELECT)
    If @error Then
    MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "No file was selected.")
    FileChangeDir(@ScriptDir)
Else
    FileChangeDir(@ScriptDir)
    $sFileOpenDialog = StringReplace($sFileOpenDialog, "|", @CRLF)
    MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "Opening the file:" & @CRLF & $sFileOpenDialog, 2 )
    run("cmd.exe")
    sleep(500)
    send("cls && " & $sFileOpenDialog & "{enter}")
    EndIf
EndFunc   ;==>Example
```

esentially, you run this program, and a popup window shows up.  It asks you to click a file that is either .bat or .exe.  The program then runs that specific program in cmd.exe.

The purpose of this is to test and debug batch files.  Here's what I mean.  If you've ever made a batch file, and it crashes before you get a chance to read what the error is?  This solves that.

**Here's what I want to know:** How can I make it, so when I right click a file that is either `.bat` or `.exe`, an option shows up that says "debug"?

once the user clicks this button, I just want the file directory to be set as a variable in a autoit script.  I can handle it from there.

I just have no idea how I can modify the registry to execute an autoit script and setting a variable.

Comment: `cmd.exe /k c:\path\to\your\file.bat` should do what your script does. You can add an option to the menu via the registry.. see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102562/how-does-one-add-a-secondary-verb-to-a-file-type-in-windows-shell) for examples.

Comment: That kinda puts my script to shame.

Comment: Lol sorry. Never mind, now you know about `cmd /k`.

Comment: http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/129955-shellfile-create-an-entry-in-the-shell-contextmenu-when-selecting-an-assigned-filetype-includes-the-program-icon-as-well/